# How can i create a directory using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can i write the name and the path of my directory that i will to create in the same node command,
like this and remove the path in my script >

`node ./stack/create.js ./path/folderName`

i´m trying to create a directory with this script but i want to remove `const path` in my script and set the path and name when i will to ran my script like this node ./stack/create.js ./path/folderName

my script

```
import fs from 'fs';

// path is where i will to create the directory and folderName is the name of the directory

// i want to write the name and path in my node command like this 

**`node ./stack/create.js ./stack/folderName`**

// i want remove this const because i dont want to open the script and change the path and name i prefer to write the path and name when i will to ran the script

const path = "./stack/004";
  
fs.access(path, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    fs.mkdir(path, {recursive: true}, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("New Directory created successfully !!");
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Given Directory already exists !!");
  }
});
```

i´m trying to create a directory with this script but i want to remove const path in my script and set the path and name when i will to ran my script like this node ./stack/create.js ./path/folderName

Comment: Look at the variable `process.argv[2]`. You can find more details about accessing script arguments here: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Comment: Consider using fs.*Sync for all fast (i.e. not reading, writing files, and 1000s file readdirs). operations Also consider checking fs/promises for asyncs

Comment: `fs.existsSync(path.join(folderName));

fs.mkdirSync(path.join(folderName));`

Comment: i made this two lines and it works fine but in my Eslint show me this error `Unexpected sync method: 'mkdirSync'.eslintno-sync`

Comment: do you why i get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
import fs from 'fs';

const path = process.argv[2];
  
fs.access(path, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    fs.mkdir(path, {recursive: true}, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("New Directory created successfully !!");
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Given Directory already exists !!");
  }
});
```